# Prove the statement involving the complex conjugate

Tags: complex-numbers

[image: How do you verify that the statement below is true?enter image description here]

How do you verify that the statement above is true? I'm not sure where to start. I know that z=x+iy and the conjugate is zbar=x-iy but how do use this knowledge?

Comment: Why not just break $z_1, z_2$ into real and imaginary parts, and compute both sides directly?

Comment: Write each of $z_1$ and $z_2$ in terms of their real and imaginary parts and use what you know.

Comment: Please do not change the question, especially after answers have been posted. Rolled back.

Comment: As @dxiv has said, *do not* replace an answered question with a new one as this invalidates existing answers and causes confusion. Instead, post the new question in a separate post, with appropriate context as described [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will take the ratio $ \ \frac{z_1}{z_2} \ $ as equal to *some* complex number $ \ u \ = \ \alpha + \beta·i  \ \neq \ 0 \ \ , $ so that the division implies that $ \ z_1 \ = \ u·z_2 \ \ . $  If we now write $ \ z_{1,2} \ = \ \mathfrak{R}_{1,2} \ + \ \mathfrak{I}_{1,2}·i \ \ ,  $ then by equating the real and imaginary parts of the product indicated, we have
$$ \mathfrak{R}_1 \ \ = \ \ \alpha·\mathfrak{R}_2 \ - \ \beta·\mathfrak{I}_2 \ \ \ , \ \ \ \mathfrak{I}_1 \ \ = \ \ \beta·\mathfrak{R}_2 \ + \ \alpha·\mathfrak{I}_2 \ \ . $$
We are not going to bother solving for the "parts" of $ \ u \ \ ; $ instead, we just want to characterize the solution.  If we set up a similar system for $ \ \frac{\overline{z_1}}{\overline{z_2}} \ = \ v \ = \ \gamma + \delta·i \ \neq \ 0 \ \ , $ we obtain
$$ \ \overline{z_1} \ = \ v·\overline{z_2} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \   \mathfrak{R}_1 \ \ = \ \ \gamma·\mathfrak{R}_2 \ + \ \delta·\mathfrak{I}_2 \ \ \ , \ \ \ -\mathfrak{I}_1 \ \ = \ \ \delta·\mathfrak{R}_2 \ - \ \gamma·\mathfrak{I}_2 \ \ .  \ $$
We find by putting these equations into correspondence that
$$ \begin{array}{c} \mathfrak{R}_1 \ \ = \ \ \alpha·\mathfrak{R}_2 \ - \ \beta·\mathfrak{I}_2 \ \ = \ \ \gamma·\mathfrak{R}_2 \ + \ \delta·\mathfrak{I}_2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (\alpha - \gamma)·\mathfrak{R}_2 \ \ = \ \ (\beta + \delta)·\mathfrak{I}_2  \\ \mathfrak{I}_1 \ \ = \ \ \beta·\mathfrak{R}_2 \ + \ \alpha·\mathfrak{I}_2 \ \ = \ \  -\delta·\mathfrak{R}_2 \ + \ \gamma·\mathfrak{I}_2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (\beta + \delta)·\mathfrak{R}_2 \ \ = \ \ -(\alpha - \gamma)·\mathfrak{I}_2 \end{array} \ \ .  $$
But since the two different sums of terms are equal to each part of $ \ z_1 \ \ , $ we have $ \ \alpha - \gamma \ = \ 0 \ \ $ and $ \ \beta + \delta \ = \ 0 \ \ . $  Thus $ \ \alpha \ = \ \gamma \ \ $ and $ \ \delta \ = \ -\beta \ \ $ (we could also have inferred this "by inspection" of the systems of equations).  We conclude that $ \ v \ = \ \overline{u} \ \ $ or
$$ \frac{\overline{z_1}}{\overline{z_2}} \ \ = \ \ \overline{\left(\frac{z_1}{z_2} \right)} \ \ . $$

You were close to finished, although you are working out more detailed expressions than really need to be seen.  You have the ratio of the conjugate numbers,
$$ \frac{(x_1 \ - \ i·y_1)·(x_2 \ + \ i·y_2)}{(x_2 \ - \ i·y_2)·(x_2 \ + \ i·y_2)} \ \ = \ \ \frac{ x_1·x_2 \ + \  y_1·y_2   }{ x^2_2 \ + \ y^2_2  } \ - \ i·\frac{x_2·y_1 \ - \  x_1·y_2}{ x^2_2 \ + \ y^2_2  } \ \ , $$
and you need to compare that to the ratio $ \ \frac{z_1}{z_2} \ \ , $ which is
$$ \frac{(x_1 \ + \ i·y_1)·(x_2 \ - \ i·y_2)}{(x_2 \ + \ i·y_2)·(x_2 \ - \ i·y_2)} \ \ = \ \ \frac{ x_1·x_2 \ + \  y_1·y_2   }{ x^2_2 \ + \ y^2_2  } \ + \ i·\frac{x_2·y_1 \ - \  x_1·y_2}{ x^2_2 \ + \ y^2_2  } \ \ , $$
which would complete your proof.

$$ \ \ $$

When you get to the "polar form" of complex numbers (which will likely be soon, if you haven't already), you can write $ \ z_1 \ = \ \rho·e^{ \ i \ · \ \theta} \ \ $ and $ \ z_2 \ = \ \sigma·e^{ \ i \ · \ \phi} \ \ , \ $ with the moduli being real numbers $ \ |z_1| \ = \ \rho \ , \ \ |z_2| \ = \ \sigma \ \ . $  The conjugates are then $ \ \overline{z_1} \ = \ \rho·e^{ \ -i \ · \ \theta} \ \ $ and $ \ \overline{z_2} \ = \ \sigma·e^{ \ -i \ · \ \phi} \ \ . $  Taking ratios  just uses the rules for division of exponential numbers, which makes the proof *much* easier to write:
$$   \frac{ z_1 }{ z_2 } \ \ = \ \  \frac{\rho·e^{ \ i \ · \ \theta}}{\sigma·e^{ \ i \ · \ \phi}} \ \ = \ \ \frac{\rho}{\sigma} \ · \ e^{( i \ · \ \theta) \ - \ ( i \ · \ \phi)} \ \ = \ \ \frac{\rho}{\sigma} \ · \ e^{ \ i \ · \ [ \ \theta  \ - \   \phi \ ]} \ \ , $$
while
$$   \frac{\overline{z_1}}{\overline{z_2}} \ \ = \ \  \frac{\rho·e^{ \ -i \ · \ \theta}}{\sigma·e^{ \ -i \ · \ \phi}} \ \ = \ \ \frac{\rho}{\sigma} \ · \ e^{( -i \ · \ \theta) \ - \ ( -i \ · \ \phi)} \ \ = \ \ \frac{\rho}{\sigma} \ · \ e^{ \ -i \ · \ [ \ \theta  \ - \   \phi \ ]} \ \ , $$
the conjugate of the first ratio.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's suppose $\text{z}_\text{n}$ where $\text{n}\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}$. Let's define:

$$\text{z}_\text{n}=\Re\left(\text{z}_\text{n}\right)+\Im\left(\text{z}_\text{n}\right)i\tag1$$

So, we get:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\overline{\text{z}_1}\pm\overline{\text{z}_2}&=\overline{\Re\left(\text{z}_1\right)+\Im\left(\text{z}_1\right)i}\pm\left(\overline{\Re\left(\text{z}_2\right)+\Im\left(\text{z}_2\right)i}\right)\\
\\
&=\Re\left(\text{z}_1\right)-\Im\left(\text{z}_1\right)i\pm\left(\Re\left(\text{z}_2\right)-\Im\left(\text{z}_2\right)i\right)\\
\\
&=\Re\left(\text{z}_1\right)-\Im\left(\text{z}_1\right)i\pm\Re\left(\text{z}_2\right)\mp\Im\left(\text{z}_2\right)i
\end{split}\tag2
\end{equation}

and:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\overline{\text{z}_1\pm\text{z}_2}&=\overline{\Re\left(\text{z}_1\right)+\Im\left(\text{z}_1\right)i\pm\left(\Re\left(\text{z}_2\right)+\Im\left(\text{z}_2\right)i\right)}\\
\\
&=\overline{\Re\left(\text{z}_1\right)+\Im\left(\text{z}_1\right)i\pm\Re\left(\text{z}_2\right)\pm\Im\left(\text{z}_2\right)i}\\
\\
&=\overline{\Re\left(\text{z}_1\right)\pm\Re\left(\text{z}_2\right)+\left(\Im\left(\text{z}_1\right)\pm\Im\left(\text{z}_2\right)\right)i}\\
\\
&=\Re\left(\text{z}_1\right)\pm\Re\left(\text{z}_2\right)-\left(\Im\left(\text{z}_1\right)\pm\Im\left(\text{z}_2\right)\right)i\\
\\
&=\Re\left(\text{z}_1\right)\pm\Re\left(\text{z}_2\right)+\left(\mp\Im\left(\text{z}_2\right)-\Im\left(\text{z}_1\right)\right)i\\
\\
&=\Re\left(\text{z}_1\right)\pm\Re\left(\text{z}_2\right)\mp\Im\left(\text{z}_2\right)i-\Im\left(\text{z}_1\right)i
\end{split}\tag3
\end{equation}

And now it is not hard to see that $(2)=(3)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you take the product conjugation rule for granted, it suffices to prove

$$\overline{\left(\frac1z\right)}=\frac1{\overline z}.$$

Indeed,

$$\overline{\left(\frac1{x+iy}\right)}=
\overline{\left(\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}\right)}=\frac1{x^2+y^2}\overline{(x-iy)}=\frac1{x^2+y^2}(x+iy)=\frac1{x-iy}.$$